# Finding cksum of cloud storage objects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hash, checksum, google-cloud-composer

We are migrating our existing shell script to be invoked from gcp cloud composer. The shell script validates the integrity of the received file by matching the received cksum with generated cksum. As gcp implementation, we are using cloud storage objects in stead of unix file system, So we will download these files to cloud storage objects. There is a challenge for us on how to use this script to finding the cksum. One option to perform the cksum is via python as cloud storage bucket is accessible from Python. Any idea if anybody has done similarly. Please find mentioned below the sample script. Thanks very much.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
#
## Validates hash value received from source
# ###################################
echo "Process started at `date +%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M:%S`"
v_file_path="$1"
v_file_name="$2"
v_control_file_name="$3"

v_startTime=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

echo "File Path : $v_file_path"
echo "Feed Name : $v_file_name"
echo "Control File Name : $v_control_file_name"

#if [ $v_checksum_type -eq 1 ]; then
        v_ht_control_file=`cat $v_file_path/$v_control_file_name | tr ' ' '\t' | cut -f 1`
        v_ht_feed=`cksum $v_file_path/$v_file_name | tr ' ' '\t' |cut -f1`
#fi
echo 'cksum defined in ctrl file:'$v_ht_control_file
echo 'cksum derived:'$v_ht_feed
```

Tried to generate cksum from Python.